# Relation#as will change behavior in 4.0. Use `map_to` instead

Tags: api, hanami

In hanami guide
https://hanamirb.org/guides/1.2/associations/has-many/#usage

when I use the method

```
@book = BookRepository.new.find_with_tickets(params[:id])
```

I got a message:

`` [deprecated] Relation#as will change behavior in 4.0. Use `map_to` instead
=> Called at:
/Users/saika/Documents/local/kadai-hanami/ticket_api/lib/ticket_api/repositories/book_repository.rb:7:in `find_with_tickets'
/Users/saika/Documents/local/kadai-hanami/ticket_api/apps/api/controllers/books/show.rb:9:in `call'
/Users/saika/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.0/gems/hanami-controller-1.2.0/lib/hanami/action/callbacks.rb:195:in `call'
/Users/saika/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.0/gems/hanami-controller-1.2.0/lib/hanami/action/callable.rb:71:in `block in call'
/Users/saika/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.0/gems/hanami-controller-1.2.0/lib/hanami/action/throwable.rb:145:in `block in _rescue'
/Users/saika/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.0/gems/hanami-controller-1.2.0/lib/hanami/action/throwable.rb:143:in `catch' ``

I do not know what should I instead use 'map_to'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you should replace `#as` with `#map_to`, and it will work as usual.